# Trouble with Securtity Alerts and Script Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, web, visual-c++

I working on a web brower in C++ using Windows Form for my final exam in high school.My problem is that i need manualy to accept Security Alerts and Script Error everytime i try to enter page on internet with my browser.

I tried web browser propertie "Script Error Suppresed" but that just hide error and give me other page to aprove that I'm sure that i want to see that page.

I expect that web browser automaticly allow certificates and allow to coninue even i have script errors.

Comment: Setting the ScriptErrorsSuppressed property to True is the simple way to load web pages with buggy Javascript code.  But a bad certificate is a much bigger problem and one you can't ignore.  Visiting such a page is quite unwise.  Pick a better web page to test your code on.

Comment: I tested it on google home page and i still need certificate to ran.We work on old Visual Studio 2008 maybe that's a problem,but i can't work on new version because they cannot see it.

Comment: UPDATE: I just tried a program on my computer and it's seems that work with errors,no java script or certificate error.That's strange.Probably school computer dosen't have certificates .